# Device to ignore one piece of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to have devices ignore a particular function on my menu. The menu is vertical and is of an accordion nature with sub menus staying open when navigating pages.

When it's viewed on devices the menu sits at the top of the page and is smaller. What I need it to do is when the item is clicked, the menu closes again so the menu is not covering the content. Heres the script keeping it open, I guess I'm looking for a if (device) ignore this line...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
 $("ul.menu-main > li").hover(function () {
    //Don't do this again if the same menu is hovered.
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        //Ensure any open sub-menu is closed.
        $("li.selected").children("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(1000);
        $("li.selected").removeClass('selected');
        //Open sub-menu
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown(1000);

    }
 });
        //Keep sub-menu open when navigating pages.
    if($('.active.parent > ul').length > 0) {
        $('.active.parent > ul').show();
    }
 });
 </script>
```

I need it to ignore this if a device is being used.

```
if($('.active.parent > ul').length > 0) {
        $('.active.parent > ul').show();
```

Hope that makes sense?!

Comment: What do you mean with "device"? What kind of device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check to see how wide the device is, and then show the menu dependent on that

```
if ($(window).width() > 960) {  // if device is wider than 960px
  if($('.active.parent > ul').length > 0) { // show menu
          $('.active.parent > ul').show();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! It works exactly how I need it to.

Comment: Make sure to put this code in a resize handler

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like you're building a responsive site. You could use [matchMedia()](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) and an if-else statement to execute different functions for different media-queries.

Here's an example from their github repo:

```
if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 480px)').matches) {
  // smartphone/iphone... maybe run some small-screen related dom scripting?
}
```

A nice alternative is [minwidth.js](https://github.com/edenspiekermann/minwidth-relocate) which let's you define callbacks for different widths

```
minwidth(600, function() {
  doSomethingLikeLoadFacebook();
});
```

Or plain jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($('.active.parent > ul').length > 0) {
      if ($(window).width() > 960) {
        $('.active.parent > ul').show();
      } else {
        $('.active.parent > ul').hide();
      }
    }
  });
  $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```